# How do I force a new record creation whenever a user navigates to a certain page?

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to force a new record to be created every time a user navigates to the page whether or not the previous record on that screen was an existing record or not.

I have `PageLoadBehavior="InsertRecord"` in my `px:PXDataSource` tag in my ASPX code for the page, which works if the user navigates to the page for the first time. The issue is if the user creates a record, navigates away, and then navigates back to that page. It will show the previous record that was on that page instead of creating a new blank record.

Comment: The very big issue here is that web technology doesn't provide any reliable mechanism to detect when the user navigates to the page. There's very little distinction between a page refresh and opening a page for the first time. Because it's expected that web connections fails very often and there's a lot of ajax going on, refreshes occur all the time. Each callback to web server is equivalent to a refresh and there's no reliable way to detect the callback was the first access to the page.

Comment: The behavior to show the previous record is tied to the session. Because in practice very often web pages fails to load and work properly the refresh functionality is used to get the user back where he was before the page stopped working. It is annoying but the only way I know to get out of it is to create a new tab in the browser which initiates a new navigation session. If we somehow find a way to break that mechanisms I believe users would be frustrated that refreshing the page make them lose the current record they were working on.

Comment: Alright, so it is a browser limitation. That's all I needed to know really. We will go down a different route then. Thanks HB!

Comment: I'd say it's more the whole philosophy of the web. When you start a desktop application there is a clear start when the program is launched. There's also a clear end when the program crash or is closed by end user. On the web connection cuts often, there's ajax glitch, session restore and unresponsive web page so the user compulsively refresh expecting the page to stay on the same document they were working in. All that and more has the consequence that there's no clear start and end to the user session. We don't precisely know if he's resuming previous work or starting new document.

Comment: HB, a functional co-worker answered the question for me. It actually is possible! I posted an answer below.

Comment: If you open a new tab I believe it should always create a new document so the URL parameter shouldn't be required. I tried to use OrderNbr=<New> in URL parameter, it does indeed open on a new document with or without the URL parameter. However as soon as you persists once the issue re-occurs for me regardless of the URL parameter. After persist I navigate to the page again by using the browser refresh button and I do not get a new document, it's still stuck on the previous one user has persisted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A functional co-worker advised me that there is a way to force a new record every time one navigates a page in Acumatica. What one needs to do is create a tile (instead of a text link) on the navigation menu, set up everything, and for the last text box, enter in &KeyField= where KeyField represents the main identifying key field of the view and  is typically the default new symbol of any record. If the symbol for a record is different, you would replace  with that symbol. Doing this will always set the page to open to a new record. Screen shot below illustrated setting up the tile:

[image]